# Nim closure doesn't update captured variable when running in thread. Why?

Tags: closures, nim-lang

I have a closure that update captured external variable. It works well when the closure is called in the same thread that variable is defined. But when I pass the closure to a child thread, it doesn't update the external variable as expected. What's happening when a closure is passed to a thread? Any docs about it?

```
# nim c -r --threads:on testClosure.nim
import strutils

template hexDumpAddrOf[T](v: T): string =
  # echo fmt"size of addr: {sizeof(v.unsafeAddr)}, sizeof ByteAddress: {sizeof(ByteAddress)}"
  var p = cast[array[sizeof(ByteAddress), uint8]](v.unsafeAddr)
  var result = ""
  for x in p:
    result = x.toHex() & result
  result

proc closureThreadProcWrapper(closure: proc() ) =
  closure()

proc testClosureThread() = 
  var thr: Thread[proc()]
  var output = @["first"]  # to be updated by thead

  echo " original addr of output:     ", hexDumpAddrOf(output) 

  proc localClosure() = 
    # The address of captured output is different from the one when running in a child thread.
    echo " localClosure addr of output: ", hexDumpAddrOf(output) 
    output.add "anything"

  localClosure()  # print the same addr as the original one. and print 
  echo "invoked closure directly and external var is updated by closure: ", output # print  @["first", "anything"]
  createThread(thr, closureThreadProcWrapper, localClosure) # print different addr of output ???

  thr.joinThread
  echo "invoked closure in child thread. external var doesn't update as expected: ", output # print  @["first", "anything"] ???

when isMainModule:
  testClosureThread()
```

The output is:

```
 original addr of output:     00007F63349C8060
 localClosure addr of output: 00007F63349C8060
invoked closure directly and external var is updated by closure: @["first", "anything"]
 localClosure addr of output: 00007F63348C9060
invoked closure in child thread. external var doesn't update as expected: @["first", "anything"]
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [manual about the memory model for threads](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#threads):

> Nim's memory model for threads is quite different than that of other common programming languages (C, Pascal, Java): Each thread has its own (garbage collected) heap, and sharing of memory is restricted to global variables. This helps to prevent race conditions. GC efficiency is improved quite a lot, because the GC never has to stop other threads and see what they reference.

In your example `output` is a local variable, not global. Hence you're modifying the threads copy not the one from the "outside".

Comment: When `output` is a global variable, the program crashes. It's still unclear how the variables are copied into a thread local stack/heap. And how to correctly pass a closure to a thread?

Comment: Interesting... it seems that the default memory management do not work with global variables in threads, it does work if you use `nim c -r --threads:on --mm:orc` or `nim c -r --threads:on --mm:arc` see https://nim-lang.org/docs/mm.html for some reason the recommended `orc` is not the default, likely some backward incompatibility.

Comment: Yes. Both orc and arc works well with the captured (local/global) variables. But the default  memory management does have some problems.